# How do I get the index of two variables, compare them, and return true or false

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am making a trivia game that uses an array of objects.

```
const questions = [
    {
        question: 'What year did the United State become independent?',
        answers: [
          { text: '1776', correct: true },
          { text: '1676', correct: false },
          { text: '1576', correct: false },
          { text: '1876', correct: false }
        ]
      },
```

I think the correct way is to get the index of the correct answer by using `.find`, getting the the index of the selected answer, then use an if statement to compare the two. If they match then the console will log "correct" or "incorrect" otherwise. I am having trouble getting the index of corretAnswer and also selectedAnswer.

When I use this code and console log it, both variables return undefined.

`const answerButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.answers-btn');`

```
function checkAnswer() {

  let correctAnswer = randomQuestion.answers.find((answer, index) => {
    return answer[index] === true;
  })

  answerButtons.forEach((answerButton, index) => {
    answerButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let selectedAnswer = answerButton[index];
      return selectedAnswer;
    })
  })
}
```

```
<button id="answers-btn-1" onclick="checkAnswer()" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-2" onclick="checkAnswer()" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-3" onclick="checkAnswer()" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-4" onclick="checkAnswer()" class="answers-btn"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to create a solution with as least code possible. First, you don't need to add an event listener to each button, you could just make each call a specific index from HTML. Secondly, since you are creating your answers list with a `correct` property, you don't need to iterate it. Just get the one the user selected and check the property.

Hope it helps.

```js
const currentQuestion = 0;

const questions = [{
  question: 'What year did the United State become independent?',
  answers: [{
      text: '1776',
      correct: true
    },
    {
      text: '1676',
      correct: false
    },
    {
      text: '1576',
      correct: false
    },
    {
      text: '1876',
      correct: false
    }
  ]
}]

function checkAnswer(bntIndex) {
  let answer = questions[currentQuestion].answers[bntIndex];
  console.log(answer.correct)
}
```

```html
<button id="answers-btn-1" onclick="checkAnswer(0)" class="answers-btn">1</button>
<button id="answers-btn-2" onclick="checkAnswer(1)" class="answers-btn">2</button>
<button id="answers-btn-3" onclick="checkAnswer(2)" class="answers-btn">3</button>
<button id="answers-btn-4" onclick="checkAnswer(3)" class="answers-btn">4</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I copied the HTML and JavaScript and it returns whether the selected answer is true or false. Sometimes though it returns false when it shouldn't and vice versa. Why do you think it would be doing that?

Comment: @postmetric it's probably related to code that's not shown in your question.  The logic in this answer is sound.  You might want to ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

when you call `.find((answer, index)`, `answer` will be an object, e.g. `{ text: '1776', correct: true }`, so when you do `return answer[index] === true` it is checking if, e.g., `{ text: '1776', correct: true }[1] === true`, but since `{ text: '1776', correct: true }` doesn't have a property `1` that will always return `false`, so `.find` will return undefined.

To get the correct answer, you would instead just do

```
let correctAnswer = randomQuestion.answers.find((answer) => answer.correct);
```

Same idea for your `forEach`, `answerButton` is already the answer, so when you do `let selectedAnswer = answerButton[index];` it will return undefined.

Comment: Thank you. How would I capture the "selectedAnswer" variable from the button that was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
const questions = [
    {
        question: 'What year did the United State become independent?',
        answers: [
            { text: '1776', correct: true },
            { text: '1676', correct: false },
            { text: '1576', correct: false },
            { text: '1876', correct: false },
        ],
    },
];

const correctAnswerIndex = questions[0].answers.findIndex((answer) => (answer.correct === true))
const correctAnswer = questions[0].answers[correctAnswerIndex];
console.log('correctAnswer', correctAnswer);

const guess = '1776';

const userAnswerIndex = questions[0].answers.findIndex((answer) => (answer.text === guess))
const userAnswer = questions[0].answers[userAnswerIndex];
console.log('userAnswer', userAnswer);

if (correctAnswer.text === userAnswer.text) {
    console.log('You win');
}
```

`Array.prototype.findIndex()` returns the index position of the first matching item, as opposed to `Array.prototype.find()` which returns the first matching item.

`findIndex` parameter is a function that returns true or false. If it evaluates to true, it returns the index position of the matching element.

There's other ways you could do it too, like for example:

```
const guess = '1776';

const answer = questions[0].answers.find((answer) => (answer.text === guess))

if (answer.correct === true) {
    console.log('You win');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am unsure what to do with the variable "guess." Is there a way to make it dynamic so that whatever button was pressed will work?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const questions = [
    {
      question: 'What year did the United State become independent?',
      answers: [
        { text: '1776', correct: true },
        { text: '1676', correct: false },
        { text: '1576', correct: false },
        { text: '1876', correct: false }
      ]
    }
];

const checkAnswer = function(index) {
  const answer = questions[0].answers[index];
  const correctAnswer = questions[0].answers.find((a) => a.correct === true);
  if (answer.text === correctAnswer.text) {
    alert('guessed correct');
  } else {
    alert('guess again');
  }
};

const answersButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.answers-btn');

for (let i = 0; i < answersButtons.length; i++) {
  answersButtons[i].innerText = questions[0].answers[i].text;
  answersButtons[i].onclick = function() {
    checkAnswer(i);
  };
}
```

```html
<button id="answers-btn-1" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-2" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-3" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-4" class="answers-btn"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Pelicer's answer, but with perhaps some more concepts that you might use:

- Delegation
- Leveraging built in features like the `value` of input elements.
- Separation of code and presentation layers
- Removal of unused elements/attributes

The method `getQuestion` is hardcoded as the selection method is out of scope for the question.

```js
const questions =
[ { question: 'What year did the United State become independent?'
  , answers: [ { text: '1576' }
             , { text: '1676' }
             , { text: '1776', correct: true }
             , { text: '1876' }
             ]
  }
]

const getQuestion = (event) => questions[0]

function checkAnswer(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('answers-btn')) {
    const question = getQuestion(event)
    const correct = question.answers.findIndex( answer => answer.correct )
    const selected = parseInt(event.target.value)
    console.log(`For the question "${question.question}", the answer "${question.answers[selected].text}" is ${ (selected == correct)?"correct":"incorrect" }`)
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer)
```

```html
<button value="0" class="answers-btn">A</button>
<button value="1" class="answers-btn">B</button>
<button value="2" class="answers-btn">C</button>
<button value="3" class="answers-btn">D</button>
```

```js
const questions =
[ { question: 'What year did the United State become independent?'
  , answers: [ { text: '1576' }
             , { text: '1676' }
             , { text: '1776', correct: true }
             , { text: '1876' }
             ]
  }
]

const getQuestion = (event) => {
  return questions[parseInt(event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-question'))]
}

function checkAnswer(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('answers-btn')) {
    const question = getQuestion(event)
    const correct = question.answers.findIndex( answer => answer.correct )
    const selected = parseInt(event.target.value)
    console.log(`For the question "${question.question}", the answer "${question.answers[selected].text}" is ${ (selected == correct)?"correct":"incorrect" }`)
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const qDiv = document.getElementById('questions')
  let qHtml = ''
  for (qi = 0; qi < questions.length; qi++) {
    qHtml += `<div data-question="${qi}">${questions[qi].question}<br />`
    for (ai = 0; ai < questions[qi].answers.length; ai++)
      qHtml += `<button value="${ai}" class="answers-btn">${questions[qi].answers[ai].text}</button>`
  }
  qHtml += '</div>'
  qDiv.innerHTML = qHtml
})
```

```html
<div id="questions">
</div>
```